# Multithreading Issues

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt4

This is more of a hypothetical question; I'm having some issues with a program and I'm wondering if it might be because of multithreading.

I have a main thread and a worker thread. The worker thread communicates with a machine through a serial port, and when it receives output from the machine, it emits a Pyqt signal. There is a slot in the main thread which receives the signal, and processes that output. The processing is a lengthy process which includes creating another object from the output.

If the worker thread were to call the main thread two times before the first output has finished getting processed, what would happen?

Comment: What you mean by `emits a signal`? Are you referring to PyQt signals?

Comment: Yes, sorry I'll put that in my question

Answer (score 1):

While your main thread is executing a long task (originated from an event), it will not process any new events. All new events will be queued in a thread-specific queue, and will be processed later when the event loop is executed. If the targeted thread is *sleeping*, the new event will be queued, and the thread will be awaken to process it.

You can read the documentation on [The Event System](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/eventsandfilters.html#sending-events).

Comment: The key point is that cross-thread signals are wrapped as events and posted to the event-queue of the thread where the receiving slot lives. The slot will be called once control returns to the event-loop and the queued signal-events can be processed (which will happen in the order they were emitted).